# html 5 canvas: Changing colour of single rectangle out of many

Tags: jquery, html, canvas

I'm having so trouble with a project ive set myself. I've been messing around with this tutorial that is a tile swapper puzzle game.

(http://hub.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-an-html5-canvas-tile-swapping-puzzle--active-10747)

What I want to do is to overlay one piece of the puzzle with a green transparent colour when the user places it in the correct place.

I know when it is in the right place, I just don't know how to change only a single pieces colour.

**Code**

```
function resetPuzzleAndCheckWin(){

        _stage.clearRect(0,0,_puzzleWidth,_puzzleHeight);
        var gameWin = true;
        var i;
        var piece;
        for(i = 0;i < _pieces.length;i++){
            piece = _pieces[i];
            _stage.drawImage(_img, piece.sx, piece.sy, _pieceWidth, _pieceHeight, piece.xPos, piece.yPos, _pieceWidth, _pieceHeight);
            _stage.strokeRect(piece.xPos, piece.yPos, _pieceWidth,_pieceHeight);

            if (piece.xPos == piece.sx && piece.yPos == piece.sy){
                alert(1);

                currentpiece = piece;

                //_stage.strokeStyle = "#CC0000";

                //_stage.currentpiece.strokeStyle = "#CC0000";


            }
```

So if you can read that, whats happening (from what I understand) is that once the user drops a puzzle piece, then the co-ordinates are saved and changed and then this function is run. This function redraws all of the puzzle pieces.

_pieces is an array of the objects

What ive done is made an if statement to check if any piece is in the correct place. (works)

I'm just not sure how to change only the correct pieces border or colour overlay. (doest work)

I've managed to change all of the pieces border colours... (see commented out line)

Comment: Just thinking but I could probably draw another rectangle around the piece? yeah that could work, ill test it out!

Comment: nah that didnt seem to work

Comment: Hmmm I seem to have something working. Whats happining is that its drawing a rectangle with my border in the correct place but then its not drawing the rest of the rectangles !!!

Answer (score 0):

DW people, i've got this all in the bag.

Here is how I solved it:

Basically I justed added a rectangle  to the correct images position, made the border BIG so that the other rectangle borders didnt outshadow it.

I then had to reset the _stage to normal for all the other rectangles.

Thats all, heres the code:

```
if (piece.xPos == piece.sx && piece.yPos == piece.sy){
            // If correct piece
                alert(1);

                _stage.strokeRect(piece.xPos, piece.yPos, _pieceWidth,_pieceHeight)
                _stage.strokeStyle = "red";
                _stage.lineWidth = 20;         

            } 

// for all the normal pieces...

            _stage.drawImage(_img, piece.sx, piece.sy, _pieceWidth, _pieceHeight, piece.xPos, piece.yPos, _pieceWidth, _pieceHeight);
            _stage.strokeRect(piece.xPos, piece.yPos, _pieceWidth,_pieceHeight);
            _stage.strokeStyle = "black"; 
            _stage.lineWidth = 2;
```